# What is the best way to search prefixes in a Map implementation?

Tags: java, string, dictionary, data-structures

```
LinkedHashMap.put("a.a1","11");        
LinkedHashMap.put("a.a12","12");        
LinkedHashMap.put("b.b1","13");        
LinkedHashMap.put("c.c1","14");        
LinkedHashMap.put("c.c1","15");
```

A search on "a." key should return two values.

Which data structure in java should we be using as Trie DS implementation is not  available. The next best which i could think of was only LinkedHashMap

Comment: You can store keys of the `HashMap` separately in the *sorted* list (and update them when needed), and then perform the binary search on that list. After that - get all the values needed from `Map`, using keys from previous step (with binary search).

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the [Apache Patricia Trie](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html). It is the exact data-structure for your use case.

From their docs:

> A PATRICIA Trie is a compressed Trie. Instead of storing all data at the edges of the Trie (and having empty internal nodes), PATRICIA stores data in every node. This allows for very efficient traversal, insert, delete, predecessor, successor, prefix, range, and select(Object) operations. All operations are performed at worst in O(K) time, where K is the number of bits in the largest item in the tree. In practice, operations actually take O(A(K)) time, where A(K) is the average number of bits of all items in the tree.
>
> Most importantly, PATRICIA requires very few comparisons to keys while doing any operation. While performing a lookup, each comparison (at most K of them, described above) will perform a single bit comparison against the given key, instead of comparing the entire key to another key.

In particular, the [`prefixMap(prefix)` operation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html#prefixMap(K)) returns a `SortedMap` view with all the entries that match the given prefix.

Again, from the docs:

> For example, if the Trie contains 'Anna', 'Anael', 'Analu', 'Andreas', 'Andrea', 'Andres', and 'Anatole', then a lookup of 'And' would return 'Andreas', 'Andrea', and 'Andres'.

Answer (score 0):

Have another map that indexes by the prefix. In particular use Guava's `Multimap` which allows a key to map to a collection values.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own `MapFilter`. I use it mostly for properties files. Essentially you pick a common prefix - say `"com."` and filter your map, selecting all entries with that prefix.

The elegance of this solution derives from the fact that the filtering process is points back to the underlying map for its values so it is truly a filter. Also, filtering filtered maps has efficiency benefits.

```
/**
 * Allows the filtering of maps by key prefix.
 *
 * Note that all access through the filter reference the underlying Map so
 * adding to a MapFilder results in additions to the Map.
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 * @param <T>
 */
public class MapFilter<T> implements Map<String, T> {
  // The enclosed map -- could also be a MapFilter.
  final private Map<String, T> map;
  // Use a TreeMap for predictable iteration order.
  // Store Map.Entry to reflect changes down into the underlying map.
  // The Key is the shortened string. The entry.key is the full string.
  final private Map<String, Map.Entry<String, T>> entries = new TreeMap<>();
  // The prefix they are looking for in this map.
  final private String prefix;

  public MapFilter(Map<String, T> map, String prefix) {
    // Store my backing map.
    this.map = map;
    // Record my prefix.
    this.prefix = prefix;
    // Build my entries.
    rebuildEntries();
  }

  public MapFilter(Map<String, T> map) {
    this(map, "");
  }

  private synchronized void rebuildEntries() {
    // Start empty.
    entries.clear();
    // Build my entry set.
    for (Map.Entry<String, T> e : map.entrySet()) {
      String key = e.getKey();
      // Retain each one that starts with the specified prefix.
      if (key.startsWith(prefix)) {
        // Key it on the remainder.
        String k = key.substring(prefix.length());
        // Entries k always contains the LAST occurrence if there are multiples.
        entries.put(k, e);
      }
    }

  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "MapFilter(" + prefix + ") of " + map + " containing " + entrySet();
  }

  // Constructor from a properties file.
  public MapFilter(Properties p, String prefix) {
    // Properties extends HashTable<Object,Object> so it implements Map.
    // I need Map<String,T> so I wrap it in a HashMap for simplicity.
    // Java-8 breaks if we use diamond inference.
    this(new HashMap<>((Map) p), prefix);
  }

  // Helper to fast filter the map.
  public MapFilter<T> filter(String prefix) {
    // Wrap me in a new filter.
    return new MapFilter<>(this, prefix);
  }

  // Count my entries.
  @Override
  public int size() {
    return entries.size();
  }

  // Are we empty.
  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return entries.isEmpty();
  }

  // Is this key in me?
  @Override
  public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return entries.containsKey(key);
  }

  // Is this value in me.
  @Override
  public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    // Walk the values.
    for (Map.Entry<String, T> e : entries.values()) {
      if (value.equals(e.getValue())) {
        // Its there!
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  // Get the referenced value - if present.
  @Override
  public T get(Object key) {
    return get(key, null);
  }

  // Get the referenced value - if present.
  public T get(Object key, T dflt) {
    Map.Entry<String, T> e = entries.get((String) key);
    return e != null ? e.getValue() : dflt;
  }

  // Add to the underlying map.
  @Override
  public T put(String key, T value) {
    T old = null;
    // Do I have an entry for it already?
    Map.Entry<String, T> entry = entries.get(key);
    // Was it already there?
    if (entry != null) {
      // Yes. Just update it.
      old = entry.setValue(value);
    } else {
      // Add it to the map.
      map.put(prefix + key, value);
      // Rebuild.
      rebuildEntries();
    }
    return old;
  }

  // Get rid of that one.
  @Override
  public T remove(Object key) {
    // Do I have an entry for it?
    Map.Entry<String, T> entry = entries.get((String) key);
    if (entry != null) {
      entries.remove(key);
      // Change the underlying map.
      return map.remove(prefix + key);
    }
    return null;
  }

  // Add all of them.
  @Override
  public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends T> m) {
    for (Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends T> e : m.entrySet()) {
      put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
  }

  // Clear everything out.
  @Override
  public void clear() {
    // Just remove mine.
    // This does not clear the underlying map - perhaps it should remove the filtered entries.
    for (String key : entries.keySet()) {
      map.remove(prefix + key);
    }
    entries.clear();
  }

  @Override
  public Set<String> keySet() {
    return entries.keySet();
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<T> values() {
    // Roll them all out into a new ArrayList.
    List<T> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, T> v : entries.values()) {
      values.add(v.getValue());
    }
    return values;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Map.Entry<String, T>> entrySet() {
    // Roll them all out into a new TreeSet.
    Set<Map.Entry<String, T>> entrySet = new TreeSet<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<String, T>> v : entries.entrySet()) {
      entrySet.add(new Entry<>(v));
    }
    return entrySet;
  }

  /**
   * An entry.
   *
   * @param <T>
   *
   * The type of the value.
   */
  private static class Entry<T> implements Map.Entry<String, T>, Comparable<Entry<T>> {
    // Note that entry in the entry is an entry in the underlying map.
    private final Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<String, T>> entry;

    Entry(Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<String, T>> entry) {
      this.entry = entry;
    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
      return entry.getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
      // Remember that the value is the entry in the underlying map.
      return entry.getValue().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public T setValue(T newValue) {
      // Remember that the value is the entry in the underlying map.
      return entry.getValue().setValue(newValue);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (!(o instanceof Entry)) {
        return false;
      }
      Entry e = (Entry) o;
      return getKey().equals(e.getKey()) && getValue().equals(e.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return getKey().hashCode() ^ getValue().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return getKey() + "=" + getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Entry<T> o) {
      return getKey().compareTo(o.getKey());
    }

  }

  // Simple tests.
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] samples = {
      "Some.For.Me",
      "Some.For.You",
      "Some.More",
      "Yet.More"};
    Map map = new HashMap();
    for (String s : samples) {
      map.put(s, s);
    }
    Map all = new MapFilter(map);
    Map some = new MapFilter(map, "Some.");
    Map someFor = new MapFilter(some, "For.");
    System.out.println("All: " + all);
    System.out.println("Some: " + some);
    System.out.println("Some.For: " + someFor);

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("namespace.prop1", "value1");
    props.setProperty("namespace.prop2", "value2");
    props.setProperty("namespace.iDontKnowThisNameAtCompileTime", "anothervalue");
    props.setProperty("someStuff.morestuff", "stuff");
    Map<String, String> filtered = new MapFilter(props, "namespace.");
    System.out.println("namespace props " + filtered);
  }

}
```